# Rotating and aligning divs

Tags: html, css, rotation, alignment

[image]

I have a series of divs aligned horizontally so that their top edges touch a horizontal line. Then for each of the horizontal divs I'd like another div immediately above, rotated 90 degrees, so that its left edge aligns with the centre of the box below it, but attaches to the same horizontal line.

Can this even be done, and can anybody show me how or point me in the right direction?!

Comment: yes. this can be done

Comment: Disclaimer: This was my first ever question on stackoverflow. I tried to include an image but that didn't work out. Here's what I'm trying to achieve: http://gurueap.com/pg_images/div_alignment.png

Comment: Had you tried this? provide your code too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A combination of flex, relative positioning and absolute positioning can do the trick:

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
body {
  padding-top: 5em;
}
.line {
  height: 1px;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0;
}
.blocks {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.h {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}
.v {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -.75em;
  height: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="line"></div>
<div class="blocks">
  <div class="h">
    <div class="v">fruits</div>
    apple<br />
    banana
  </div>
  <div class="h">
    <div class="v">carrot</div>
    parsnip<br />
    vegetables
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without absolute positioning, by using just flexbox. Here's an example: https://codepen.io/palash/pen/OzrpKJ

```
 <div class='boxes'>
  <div class='vertical'>
    <div class="box">fruits</div>
    <div class="box">carrot</div>
  </div>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class='horizontal'>
    <div class="box">
      apple
      banana
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      parsnip
      vegetables
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.boxes {
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.line {
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  margin: 0;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.horizontal, .vertical {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.vertical {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  flex-direction: column;
  .box {
    border-left: 0;
    &:first-child {
      transform: translateY(-20px);
    }
  }
}

.horizontal {
   .box {
    border-top: 0;
  }
}
```